# What is the characteristic equation of $a_{n+2}+2a_{n}=0$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, characteristic-polynomial

So if we let $a_{n}=Cr^n$ then we have $Cr^{n+2}+2Cr^n=Cr^n(r^2+2)$. So I got that the characteristic equation $r^2+2=0$ but it should be $r^2+2r=0$ apparently. How is that?

Comment: Why do you think it should be $r^2+2r$?  Note that $(-2)^n$ is not a solution to your recursion, but that $\left( \sqrt {-2}\right)^n$ is, so to speak.

Comment: I thought it was wrong but my teacher wrote it so I just wanted to be sure.

Comment: Then you should change "apparently" to "according to my teacher" in the question because you don't actually mean that it is apparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characteristic equation of :
$$a_{n + 2} + \alpha a_{n + 1} + \beta a_n = 0$$
is :
$$r^2 + \alpha r + \beta = 0$$
In your case $\alpha = 0$ and $\beta =2$.